# setVisibilty() wont work first time

Tags: android, android-layout, view, visibility

I have a layout called a controller in it i have a couple buttons and such
the problem is in my onTouch function i want to show it on one click and hide it on another. Now this works after 2 touches. The first touch is supposed to show the controller while the next is supposed to make it disappear. The first and second touches do nothing but on the third touch it works. Here are the related functions for this

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{

    int eventx = event.getAction();
    switch(eventx)
    {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        if(isLifted)
        {
            if(!isVisible)
            {
                Log.i("onTouch", "called showPuse menu");
                isVisible = true;
                isPaused = true;
                showPauseMenu();
            }
            else if(isVisible)
            {
                hidePauseMenu();
                isVisible= false;
            }
            isLifted = false;

        }
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        if(!isLifted)
        {
            isLifted = true;
            //Log.i("onTouchEvent", "Lifted");
        }
    }
    return false;
}

    /***************************************************
 * Shows All Views needed to be shown
 * Also pauses video and audio
 *
 * *************************************************/
private void showPauseMenu()
{
    Log.i("showPauseMenu", "called");
    playButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Log.i("showPauseMenu", "plaButton visible");
    bottomButtons.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Log.i("showPauseMenu", "bottom Menu showed");
    playButton.invalidate();
    bottomButtons.invalidate();
    pauseMedia();
}
/************************************************
 * Hides Views that are part of Pause Menu
 * Also starts video and audio back again
 */
private void hidePauseMenu() {
    playButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    bottomButtons.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    playMedia();
}
```

Can anyone say what the problem might be? I've been looking at this code for a couple of days now and cant see what it might be.

Comment: is this java or android? if so, tagging it as such might be helpful.

Comment: What is this? Java? is it for Android? Add the language and other relevant tags and people might be able to help you.

Comment: android I forgot to put that up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few pointers about this code:

- The isLifted variable presumably starts out false, and on the first touch event it causes nothing to happen on the down event. When the user lifts his/her finger the variable is set to true so the second event can actually be processed. This means the first touch will never have any visible effect.
- You're using an isVisible boolean instead of just checking the visibility of the components themselves. This makes it very easy to get them out of sync.

Without the full class it's hard to tell, but I'd investigate both these points.

Comment: The isLifted variable starts out true so that was not the problem. The other one was. The visibility was out of sync i guess. I changed to getVisibilty == View.Gone and now it works as it should thanks.

Answer (score 0):

While designing the xml make the widget `android:visibility="gone"`. During the program check the state if its hidden onclick set `View.VISIBLE` and if visible on second touch`View.GONE`.

I think this will work. Try it once.